# Maxent error 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:"Z^,,,"'

Tags: qgis, maxent

I converted a shp file into asc file in QGIS. Then I tried running the Maxent with that enviromental layer and came across that error message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:“Z^,,,”
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: one of your number fields has a Z in it - open the file with a text editor and look for the problem.

Comment: How did you export the raster file? I suggest that this Maxent error is caused because your raster is actually GeoTIFF with `.asc` extension. Run `gdalinfo` from comamnd line or in QGIS`'Information...` from processing toolbox. Check the *Driver:* value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is caused because your raster is **actually GeoTIFF** file with `.asc` extension, which is unsupported by MaxEnt.

You can check this in raster metadata (or by running `gdalinfo` from comamnd line, or in QGIS `Information...` from processing toolbox). Check the *Driver:* value.

[image]

**Cause:**

You converted your `.shp` with `Raster -> Conversion -> Rasterize (Vector to Raster)...`  which runs `gdal_rasterize` and create GeoTIFF (default output) even if you choose other format. In this case a warrning message should appear:

[image]

**Solution:**

You can fix your raster file with `Raster -> Conversion -> Translate (Convert Format)...`  (which runs `gdal_translate`). As output format choose `Arc/Info ASCII Grid`.

Notice the `-of AAIGrid` argument in the gdal_translate command preview:

```
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid /source/path/source.asc /output/path/fixedascraster.asc
```

*Note:*

I think (according to GDAL documentation [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html)), editing `gdal_rasterize` command with addition `-of AAIGrid` argument should also work , but this gives me unsupported format error <s>for some reason, but you can give it try</s>.

---

*edit: clarification of note:*

According to GDAL documentation [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html), you can edit `gdal_rasterize` command with addition `-of` argument, and define output type. But in this case it doesn't work for `AIIGrid`.

Running `gdal_rasterize -of AIIGrid..` from command line leads to error which tells you that `AAIGrid` does not support direct output creation

```
ERROR 6: Output driver `AAIGrid' not recognised or does not support direct output file creation.
```

Checking this with `gdalinfo --formats` gives you:

```
AAIGrid -raster- (rwv): Arc/Info ASCII Grid
```

Acording to [this message](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2014-August/039813.html) from gdal-dev mailing list the capabilities are:

> r: rear
>
> w: write "Create dataset by copying another"
>
> v: supports virtual IO - eg. /vsimem/

Which means that is still supported for translating with `gdal_translate`

Comment: I followed your instructions and was able to run Maxent, thank you. But now i have a different problem regarding the colours of the model map.

Comment: @Idoia You're welcome :). If you don't find any question post with suitable answer, don't hesitate to create new one.