# Converting .tif to .asc for MaxEnt

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, esri-ascii-raster, maxent

I want to convert some .tifs to .asc to use in MaxEnt.

I have tried using both ArcGIS 10.5.1 (the "Raster to ASCII" tool) and QGIS 2.14.3 (Raster > Translate tool). Both give .asc files, but when I try to run MaxEnt I get this;

```
Error reading "File": java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string "nan"
```

This happens even when I only include a single layer in MaxEnt, so I know it is not an issue about all layers having matching extents. I've seen [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244886/maxent-error-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-stringz#245001) with a similar issue, which suggested the files were still GeoTiffs, but I've checked them and they are definitely .asc

Is there an obvious thing I'm missing?

---

**Edit**

Here is the first few lines of the file, when opened in a text editor
[image]

---

**Further edit**

Link to the original multiband .tif is [here](https://stir.box.com/s/8mbsvbzqplrknwbhjskx4o2g8s553xxw). The single band .asc with `Nan` is [here](https://stir.box.com/s/nuicx0zoldi3pagvxpmd9x9xhyev93h4), and the band with the `Nan` corrected to `-9999` is [here](https://stir.box.com/s/9q8e2iikl05gtep2koyaw4mz5dxemv1t)

Comment: What do the first few lines of your asc files look like? They should start with lines like "NCOLS 654" and "NROWS 555" and a "NODATA_value -9999" or similar. Followed by the values as numbers. If the string "nan" occurs anywhere then something isn't right. Open in a text editor and check.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman, I've added a screenshot of the first few rows. Looks like there is a problem with `Nan` values in there.

Comment: Yikes. If you can do a string-search-and-replace in your text editor and change all those `1.#QNAN` to `-9999` then it *should* read in.... How they got in there I do not know... If we could get the original TIF I could investigate...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Spacedman. I changed them to `-9999` in the text editor, and I can now use them in MaxEnt. It would still be good to know _how_ they were introduced in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in your original TIFF is stored as "Float64 - Sixty four bit floating point". This is a standard binary format for decimal numbers. The standard includes special binary numbers for encoding infinity, minus-infinity, and a special set of codes for "Not a Number". For example, if you divide 0 by 0 you get "Not a number" - here's R doing that:

```
> 0/0
[1] NaN
```

There's not one single binary pattern that represents "Not a number", there can be many.

Now note that "Not a number" is different to "No data". In raster imagery there's often a need to flag "No data" areas where the image hasn't been taken. The conventional way to do this is to use a "special" numeric value, often way out of the range of the real data, and use that. So you'll see areas with the value -9999 in rasters of temperature.

The GeoTIFF format supports this way of flagging "No data" areas with a special numeric value. and you'll see that in QGIS' properties. When you save such a raster to an ASC format, its in the header:

```
NCOLS 204 
NROWS 228 
XLLCORNER 96.546435161 
YLLCORNER 16.511034922 
CELLSIZE 0.00449157642156861 
NODATA_value -3.4e+38
```

But what you have in your TIFF is "Not a number". Perhaps someone divided a raster with zeroes by another raster with zeroes, resulting in a large area of "Not a numbers". TIFF is fine with that, it happily stores the pixels as "Not a number" codes.

But what to do when you save as an ASCII file? QGIS, via the `gdal` utilities, does this:

```
ncols        204
nrows        228
xllcorner    96.546435160746
yllcorner    16.511034922117
cellsize     0.004491576421
 nan nan nan nan nan nan [etc] 791.8 [etc etc]
```

faithfully spitting out the "not a number" string. But there's no real standard for what the string representation of "not a number" codes looks like (R uses "NaN", for example) so this is now going to have problems. It looks like ArcGIS is using a similar but different code for printing "not a number".

Things you should do: find out how the "not a number" codes got in there - read any metadata and ask anyone who is responsible for the file; check if the "not a number" codes are meaningful - perhaps they are regions where someone has done a divide 0 by 0; check if the "not a number" codes are just a proxy for "No Data" pixels, in which case replace them with true "No Data" values, such as -9999, and set that as the "No Data" pixel value in the raster properties.

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed answer. The original files came from a Google Earth Engine download, and the no data value has not been defined. I will try to sort those. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the gdal_translate commandline tool:

```
gdal_translate yournewraster.tif -of AAIGrid existingascraster.asc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please can you give me a bit more direction as to how I should use this? Where is the gdal_translate tool?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using windows?  gdal_translate commandline app comes with the gdal/ogr suite of tools.  https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries  will provide some links to download...you can either compile if you are into that or there are binaries(pre-built).

Comment: Thanks, I found the gdal_translate tool in the processing toolbox. (I mainly use QGIS on Mac). I can convert the file, but have the same issue as above, the only difference being the `1#QNAN` entries are now `nan`. @Spacedman's suggestion is a reasonable workaround, but I'm still keen to find out why this is happening.